# ElasticSearch bool query combined with should and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

in elasticsearch do you know why

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              conditions1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              conditions2
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        conditions3
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

always finds the documents if the condition3 is true
even when condition2 and condition1 is false

Comment: You need to move `must` up at the same level as `filter`, remove `should`

Comment: but I want at least one of the conditions under should to be successful and condition3 should always be passed

Comment: @Val updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html:

> If the bool query is in a query context and has a must or filter
>   clause then a document will match the bool query even if none of the
>   should queries match. In this case these clauses are only used to
>   influence the score. If the bool query is a filter context or has
>   neither must or filter then at least one of the should queries must
>   match a document for it to match the bool query. This behavior may be
>   explicitly controlled by settings the minimum_should_match parameter.

Comment: @fatihtekin in contrary, I think Thomas is right, you need to add `minimum_should_match: 1` if you want to make sure at least one should clause matches.

Comment: @fatihtekin sorry, I try to give you some clue, so you can think by yourself and learn something. Here, I have just copy/paste documentation because the solution is obvious, I am not going to spend more time to read and explain documentation for you, sorry.

Comment: hey Thomas, I tried and it works thanks and sorry for not reading your comments more carefully. Appreciate both of your help. Thanks million

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping shoulds into the must solved the problem. Please, let me know if anyone has a cleaner solution

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      condition1
                    },
                    {
                      condition2
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          condition3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```